# Idiomatic R for splitting a column that may be splitted into list/vector with irregular length, in a dataframe or equivalent?

Tags: r, clojure

I'm struggling to implement the following requirement in R:

For example, for the following dataframe:

```
Multiple_rows <- data.frame(rbind(c("FLASH, SWAP.", "Memory: FLASH"), c("FLASH, , ,, SWAP.", "Memory: FLASH")))
colnames(Multiple_rows)<- c("VARIANTS", "STANDARD")
Multiple_rows
#           VARIANTS      STANDARD
#1      FLASH, SWAP. Memory: FLASH
#2 FLASH, , ,, SWAP. Memory: FLASH
```

1. For each row, split the value at the column VARIANTS, which contains ',' as separator.
2. With the resulted list of strings, for each element in it, trim the
   white spaces in both front, and end, and filter out those blank
   element.
3. With the  the cleaned list, for each element in it, create
       a row with two column: column STANDARD with the original value of
       the row being processed,  column VARIANT with the element in
       question.
4. Collect all those newly created rows into a new
           table/dataframe.

So for the above example, I'd like to have the following as the result:

```
#     VARIANT STANDARD      
#1 "FLASH" "Memory FLASH"
#2 "SWAP." "Memory FLASH"
#3 "FLASH" "Memory FLASH"
#4 "SWAP." "Memory FLASH"
```

The order of the rows does not matter.

Below is my implementation of in Clojure (to illustrate my requirement):

```
(def Multple-rows 
[{:VARIANTS "FLASH, SWAP.", :STANDARD "Memory: FLASH"}
{:VARIANTS "FLASH, , ,, SWAP.", :STANDARD "Memory: FLASH"}]) ;; This is my input. The input equivalent to a data frame with 2 column of "STANDARD", and "VARIANTS"

(defn variants-decomposed [a_map_raw] ;; process each row of the input data
  (if-let [variants (:VARIANTS a_map_raw)]
    (if (clojure.string/blank? variants)
      [{:STANDARD (:STANDARD a_map_raw), :VARIANT nil}]
      (let [standard (:STANDARD a_map_raw)
            splitted (-> (clojure.string/split variants #"[,]")
                         ((fn [list-variant] (map #(clojure.string/trim %) list-variant)), )
                          ((fn [list-variant] (filter #(not (clojure.string/blank? %)) list-variant)), ))]
        (if (seq splitted) ;; not empty
          (for [v splitted] {:STANDARD standard, :VARIANT v})
          [{:STANDARD standard, :VARIANT nil}]
           )))
    [{:VARIANT nil, :STANDARD (:STANDARD a_map_raw)}])
    )
(defn multiple-variant-maps [map_of_variants] ;; the processing to each row and collect the result
  (-> (map variants-decomposed map_of_variants)
      ((fn [list-of-vectors] (apply concat list-of-vectors)), )))))

(multiple-variant-maps Multple-rows) ;; This is my required result, which is equivalent to a data frame of 2 columns of "STANDARD", and "VARIANT".
```

Here are the results of the above computation:

```
({:STANDARD "Memory: FLASH", :VARIANT "FLASH"} 
{:STANDARD "Memory: FLASH", :VARIANT "SWAP."} 
{:STANDARD "Memory: FLASH", :VARIANT "FLASH"} 
{:STANDARD "Memory: FLASH", :VARIANT "SWAP."})
```

I wish that I could do the equivalent in R idiomatically. So far, I have struggled to get the following, but it still does not handle the irregularity of blank variants, etc.

```
dictionary.cleaned <- function(t) {
    variants.splitted <- sapply(data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(t[, "VARIANTS"], "[,]"))), str_trim)
    melted <- melt(data.frame(dplyr::select(t, -VARIANTS), variants.splitted), id.vars = "STANDARD")

    colnames(melted)[colnames(melted)== "value"] <- "VARIANT"
    melted
  }
```

Here are the result of the above R code:

```
> dictionary.cleaned(Multiple_rows)
        STANDARD variable VARIANT
1  Memory: FLASH       X1   FLASH
2  Memory: FLASH       X1   FLASH
3  Memory: FLASH       X2   SWAP.
4  Memory: FLASH       X2        
5  Memory: FLASH       X3   FLASH
6  Memory: FLASH       X3        
7  Memory: FLASH       X4   SWAP.
8  Memory: FLASH       X4        
9  Memory: FLASH       X5   FLASH
10 Memory: FLASH       X5   SWAP.
```

I'd like to learn to program more fluently in R dealing with list/vector with R's equivalent to list comprehension, and that equivalent to list concatenation, as well as converting list expression to data frame properly.

Or I may need to learn R's paradigm of dealing with data with such complexity, or irregularity. (R's very elegant in dealing neatly structured vectors.)

Or maybe, I should use the right tool for the right job that such lower level data wrangling might not be good candidate with R?

Thanks for your help or pointers!

Yu

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example and the expected result? I think R can handle this.

Comment: If you're OK with using a package: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(Multiple_rows, "VARIANTS", ",", "long")[VARIANTS != ""]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# replace spaces with blanks in VARIANTS column
Multiple_rows$VARIANTS <- gsub(" ", "", as.character(Multiple_rows$VARIANTS))
# replace repeated commas with a single comma
Multiple_rows$VARIANTS <- gsub(",+", ",", as.character(Multiple_rows$VARIANTS))

VARIANTS <- unlist(strsplit(Multiple_rows$VARIANTS, ","))
STANDARD <- rep(Multiple_rows$STANDARD, 
                sapply(strsplit(Multiple_rows$VARIANTS, ","), length))

Multiple_rows <- data.frame(VARIANTS, STANDARD)
#  VARIANTS      STANDARD
#1    FLASH Memory: FLASH
#2    SWAP. Memory: FLASH
#3    FLASH Memory: FLASH
#4    SWAP. Memory: FLASH
```

Comment: thanks for so elegant, and intuitive solution in fraction of seconds! It took me more time to validate! Very impressed.

Comment: No problem!  For an even more elegant, one-line solution, take a look at the `cSplit` answer by @AnandaMahto

Answer (score 4):

Here are two alternatives to consider.

The first uses `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. It returns a `data.table`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(Multiple_rows, "VARIANTS", ",", "long")[VARIANTS != ""]
#    VARIANTS      STANDARD
# 1:    FLASH Memory: FLASH
# 2:    SWAP. Memory: FLASH
# 3:    FLASH Memory: FLASH
# 4:    SWAP. Memory: FLASH
```

The second uses "dplyr" and "tidyr", with "stringi" loaded for trimming the strings:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

Multiple_rows %>%
  mutate(VARIANTS = lapply(strsplit(as.character(VARIANTS), ","), stri_trim)) %>%
  unnest(VARIANTS) %>%
  filter(VARIANTS != "")
#   VARIANTS      STANDARD
# 1    FLASH Memory: FLASH
# 2    SWAP. Memory: FLASH
# 3    FLASH Memory: FLASH
# 4    SWAP. Memory: FLASH
```

Comment: thanks for your also elegant solutions! I'll take a closer look of your splitstackshape package.

Comment: To both Frank, and Ananda, to me, as struggling student of R, what's your recommendation of study materials to get more  fluent with R. It's very challenging to develop the intuition of reasoning in terms of vectors operations, and manipulation. The intuition of Lisp is still quite scalar, and sequential, less abstract in this regard. Thanks again!

Comment: @YuShen, most of what I've learnt has been through hanging out here and seeing some of the pros in action :-)

Comment: *The Art of R Programming* by Norman Matloff is a good book for learning about data manipulation in R, as well as other useful skills.  There are other books that focus on statistics in R.